Flex Grid Not Flexing
I'm trying to understand flex boxes.  I've written this code here:


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}


/* cell block */

.page-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: green;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* row within cell block */

.content-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}


/* element within row */

.inner-wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* any content inside a row element */

.content {
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.width-3 {
  width: 30%;
}
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="content-row">
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text1.inner text1.inner text1.inner text1.inner text1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text2.inner text2.inner text2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text3.inner text3.inner text3.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-row">
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text4.inner text4.inner text4.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text5.inner text5.inner text5.inner text5.inner text5.inner text5.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text6.inner text6.inner text6.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



The boxes are being cut off and I don't want that to happen.  When I add a fixed height of at least ~300px to 'page-content' or lots of text to the 'content' blocks, things size a little better.  It looks like the 'inner-wrapper' is taller than the 'content-row'.  Why is this happening?
I basically just want two rows with three elements each that fill up all available space.  Each row should take 50% of the vertical space and each row element should occupy 33% of the horizontal space.  If more rows or elements are added, the spacing should adjust proportionally.
I want to stay away from using vh and vw.

So what you need to do is this:
For page-rows to occupy exactly 50% you need the flex: 0 0 50% property in the rows, else you could use flex: 1 1 auto so that each rows occupies space depending on its content height in this case. Keep in mind that if the content ends up to be bigger than the container height it would adjust accordingly.
Notice you can also use the gap property to create the necessary distance between flex items.


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}


/* cell block */

.page-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: green;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* row within cell block */

.content-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  flex:0 0 50%;
}


/* element within row */

.inner-wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* any content inside a row element */

.content {
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.width-3 {
  width: 33.333%;
}
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="content-row">
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text1.inner text1.inner text1.inner text1.inner text1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text2.inner text2.inner text2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text3.inner text3.inner text3.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-row">
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text4.inner text4.inner text4.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text5.inner text5.inner text5.inner text5.inner text5.inner text5.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper width-3">
      <h3 class="content">HEADER</h3>
      <p class="content">inner text6.inner text6.inner text6.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



